# App Crashes while connecting activities

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Am going through the tutorial in the below link to have a simple Android App with more than one activities.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

I have followed the steps as specified in the android tutorial, I run into a NullPointer Exception on the EditText Widget,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Below is my MainActivity.java where the exception as editText returns Null though I assume I have wired it in the right way,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.my.application.message";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent( this , DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText;
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

    System.out.println("the values is "+ editText);

    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);

   }
}
```

And below is the activity_main.xml ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/do_send"
     android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any pointers here to get past this ?

Comment: `EditText` is in Activity layout instead of in `view` (which is instance of clicked View(in your case it is Button)), so just access it without `view` like :`editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);`

Comment: where did you call your "sendMessage" and don't use "view." , initialise without this.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK is right.

Comment: When you are calling sendMessage?

Comment: he is calling from layout onclick

Comment: @NehaK: Here `android:onClick="sendMessage"`

Comment: Thank you  ρяσѕρєя K for the pointers, that fixed it.

Comment: @Rotwang - This question isn't around the NullPointer exception in general but to the activity scenario mentioned here. So it isn't a duplicate question or at least isn't the duplicate of question tagged .

Comment: @AshwinSridhar Nooooo... What is not clear in `I run into a NullPointer Exception on the EditText Widget`?

Answer (score 2):

on line of click :

```
   editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

"view" is that button. and by using `view.findViewById`, you are trying to find required view in that button (which is not parent of you EditText). So you should try following ways :

Direct :

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

here `findViewById` will try to find id in current Activity.

using parentView :

```
editText = (EditText) (view.getParent().findViewById(R.id.edit_message));
```

here your `button's` parent is `EditText's` parent, so it will find you `EditText` by this code also.

Comment: Thank you NehaK , the explanation is very crisp and to the point.

Comment: welcome!..please my answer as right.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is in an `Activity` so you don't need to do `view.findViewById()`. Instead, simply do the following :

```
EditText editText;
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NullPoint` address to those objects which has null values, put proper id and code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.my.application.message";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent( this , DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText;
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); //here

    System.out.println("the values is "+ editText);

    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find an `EditText` from the clicked `button`

```
editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

You have to find it from the Activity

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

Read that tutorial again, you'll spot the difference

Answer (score 0):

As advice, I would first seek that it is not null or empty.

```
       if(editText != null && !editText.getText.toString.equals("")) {
            ...
       }
```

After  I would follow the advice of ρяσѕρєя K:

> EditText is in Activity layout instead of in view (which is instance
>   of clicked View(in your case it is Button)), so just access it without
>   view like :editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);